# Extract link with regex

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How can I extract all links with regex?

Link example:

```
<a class="link" title="somehing" href="https://www.website.com/link" data-jsid="anchor" target="_blank"> (more html stuff..)

I want to this: https://www.website.com/link
```

I try something like this, but not enough specific.

```
  href=""(.*?)"".*?>(.*?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
href="([^"]+)"
```

- `[^"]+` matches anything other than a `"`

Example : http://regex101.com/r/lA8nD8/1

Here the capture groupo 1 will contain the string

```
https://www.website.com/link
```

**OR**

You can also use a non greedy `.+?` as

```
href=".+?"
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/lA8nD8/2

**OR**

You can try a lookbehind

```
(?<=href=")([^"]+)
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/lA8nD8/3

Comment: without "href=" tag. And if you can, please post me only VB compatible regex. I really bad in regex.